# Puppeteer-cluster using tab and taking screenshot

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I am using puppeteer-clustor and imagemagick (convert) / xwd command to take screenshot of complete desktop.

Would need browser with viewable part of page and browser navigation buttons and URL. I could get screenshot most of the times, however it does fail other times.

Error message is the tab is closed screenshot is done. Please suggest what is that I am doing wrong.

Code runs on linux with a X running on DISPLAY:0.3. I can see

Below is the code which I have I tried blockingWait and also

````
const {
  Cluster
} = require('puppeteer-cluster');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

process.env['DISPLAY'] = ':0.3';
let i = 0;

function wait(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function blockingWait(seconds) {
  //simple blocking technique (wait...)
  var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000);
  while (waitTill > new Date()) {}
}

function getscreenshot(url, page) {
  page.bringToFront(); // Get the tab to focus 
  wait(200);
  i = i + 1; // For now get screenshot as number will add image named based on URL 
  path = i + '.jpg';
  var r = execSync('import -window root ' + path);
  console.log('Taken screenshot: ' + path);
  console.log(url);
  blockingWait(1);
}

(async () => {
  // Create a cluster with 6 workers or 6 tabs which loads all the url
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
    maxConcurrency: 6,
    timeout: 120000,
    puppeteerOptions: {
      executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable',
      args: [
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--incognito',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--window-size=1600,1200',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--disable-gpu'
      ],
      headless: false, //headless:false so we can watch the browser as it works
    },
  });
  console.log('cluster launched');

  // We don't define a task and instead use own functions
  const screenshot = async ({
    page,
    data: url
  }) => {
    console.log('screenshot entered ');
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      'CUSTOMER-ID': "66840"
    }, ); // use same customer id as header
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1600,
      height: 1200
    });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    }, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    }, {
      waitUntil: 'load'
    });
    // Since we wait the page to fully load

    await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok()) // ok page is ready .. will deal here for other HTTP error beside 200, 404,500 etc 

    await page.waitForNavigation({
      waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    }, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    }, ); // Wait for page to load before screenshot
    await page.bringToFront(); // Get the tab to focus 
    wait(100); // Blocking wait
    console.log('Waiting 5 sec');
    blockingWait(5); // different kind of wait
    getscreenshot(url, page);
    console.log('screenshot exited');
  };

  const extractTitle = async ({
    page,
    data: url
  }) => {
    console.log('scrapelinks entered');
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      'CUSTOMER-ID': "66840"
    }, );
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1600,
      height: 1200
    });
    await page.goto(url);
    const pageTitle = await page.evaluate(() => document.title); // will later used to confirm the page matches with client details.
    // get all Links on the page
    const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', hrefs => hrefs.map((a) => {
      return {
        href: a.href,
        text: a.textContent,
      };
    }));
    // get 1st links matching text or link value having bioanalyzer-systems/instrument-2100.xhtml
    for (let postUrl of hrefs) {
      if (postUrl.text.indexOf("Client-s") > -1) {
        cluster.execute(postUrl.href, screenshot); // add this link also to queue
      } else if (postUrl.href.indexOf("bioanalyzer-systems/instrument-2100.xhtml") > -1) {
        cluster.execute(postUrl.href, screenshot); // add this url to queue
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('scrapelinks exited');
  };

  // Make screenshots
  cluster.execute('http://www.internal-site.int/en/product/66840?product=NEW&CodeList=bio&Id=66840', screenshot);
  cluster.execute('http://www.internal-site.int/en/product/66840?product=USED&CodeList=nonbio&Id=66840', screenshot);

  // But also do some other stuff
  cluster.execute('http://www.internal-site.int/en/product/66840?product=NEW&CodeList=bio&Id=66840', extractTitle);
  cluster.execute('http://www.internal-site.int/en/product/66840?product=USED&CodeList=nonbio&Id=66840', extractTitle);

  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
})();```

I expect output to take screenshot once the page or tab load is completed.
````

Answer (score 1):

The page is being closed as soon as the function is finished executing (or the Promise is resolved). You are not using `await` to wait for the asynchronous action to finish.

For example, in your `screenshot` function, there is the following code:

```js
wait(100);
console.log('Waiting 5 sec');
blockingWait(5);
getscreenshot(url, page);
console.log('screenshot exited');
```

The first line calls the `wait` function (which is `async`), but as you are not `await`ing it, the function will be executed in the background and Node.js will continue to execute your script.

The `blockingWait` is not the JavaScript-like way to write code. This completely blocks the execution.

The `getscreenshot` function should again be `async` so that you can `await` it. Also, some of the puppeteer function calls should have `await` in front of them (e.g. `page.bringToFront`) to wait until they are finished.

In general, you should check out the concept of [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and Promises to understand where and why you should be using these keywords.

Comment: I am not sure how to resolve this. I have used Promise as suggested in another post. However it does not work .  await page.bringToFront(); and then taking screenshot. But this does not help. Something like ```  await Promise.all([
     page.bringToFront(),
      execSync('import -window root ' + path +'.jpg'), 
      screenshot(page,url),
      console.log(`closing page: ${url}`),
      page.close(),
        ]);
```  .. Any suggestion how to make page come to front .. wait for page to display fully and then take a screenshot using import (imagemagick utility).